# I have an error where it says firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have never used this cite for project questions before so this may be formatted wrong.

So I'm using firebase for a project to build a web app. For some reason I am getting an error where it says firebase is undefined even though I have the scripts in the program and from what I understand it should be defined properly. I have tried putting the code on the main index page and in the JavaScript itself but neither seems to work.
[error shown in developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSghx.png)

```
    enter code<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="homePage">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Happy+Monkey&family=Lemon&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa Slab One' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!--firebase scripts-->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-firestore.js"></script>


    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
          firebase code provided
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
        const auth = firebase.auth();
    </script>
    <script  src="app.js"></script>
    <script  src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for the JS login

```
    / Your web app's Firebase configuration
 var firebaseConfig = {
  code from firebase
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
const auth = firebase.auth();


function setUpThePage() {
    
  var button = document.getElementById("enterButton");
  button.addEventListener("click", Click);
}

function Click() {
    // Gets the input form the boxes
    let emailbox = document.getElementById('emailBox');
    let passwordBox = document.getElementById('passwordBox');

    let email = emailbox.value;
    let password = passwordBox.value;
   //variable scopping 
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
      let outputElement = document.getElementById('outputMessage');
      outputElement.textContent =  "email= " + email + "password= " + password + " This will work.";
  
    });


}

window.onload = setUpThePage;
```

Comment: `firebase-app.js` has to be the first script. Also, not sure you're supposed to initialize firebase twice? You're doing that in the inline script in the HTML file and again in your login script.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase App script Should be added before other scripts in the index.html file:-

```
    <!--firebase scripts-->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```